# Why do stock buybacks raise the price of stocks?

Tags: stocks

I don't understand why a buyback would fundamentally raise the price of a stock. Consider a company with $1000K in the bank and annual earnings of $100K. What would be the fair price of this company? Assuming P/E 20 the earnings stream is worth $2000K and if we add the money in the bank its $3000K. Assume the company has 1000 shares, then the price should be $3000 per share.

Now consider the company buying up 200 shares for a total of  $600K. The company will then have $400K in the bank. Its earn stream is still worth $2000K so the new valuation is $2400K. However, the company now only has 800 outstanding shares, so that again gives a share price of $3000. In other words, the buyback didn't affect the share price as all.

Of course, if we disregard the money in the bank and look from a "earnings per share" perspective, then the companies share would go up (because there are fewer shares to divide the earnings on) but surely we also need to consider the money held by a company when doing the valuation. Consider for instance a company with $1000K in the bank and earnings on $1/year. Surely this company would be worth more than the $20 you might get at P/E = 20.

Comment: A buyback reduces outstanding shares and therefore increases EPS, return on assets  and return on equity, all  making a company appear more attractive.

Comment: Why do you assume P/E is the only thing that affects the share price? Free cash (which _does_ change in buy-backs) is another important piece of analysis.

Comment: @Aganja: If you read my question, that's exactly what I am asking. If that is taken into account, stock price shouldn't change from a buyback.